# Transpile typescript into plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

Something is a bit cloudy in my mind which is the following.
I have a module written in typescript which will be imported later in some html pages.

sdk.ts

```
export class PM {

  header: any;
  headerLink: string;
  headerDiv: any;

  /**
   * @todo remove constructor.
   */
  constructor(mode: string) {
    if (mode == null || mode == undefined) {
      this.buildGUI();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Build GUI.
   * It builds the GUI by wrapping the body in a container, adding the header and sidebar.
   */
  buildGUI(): void {
    this.initAndCreateComponents();
    this.insertScript(this.headerLink);
  }

  /**
   * Insert script.
   * It inserts the script's import tag in the head of the document.
   * @param {string} scriptLink - script's link to be loaded.
   */
  insertScript(scriptLink: string): void {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scriptLink;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };

  /**
   * Init and Create Components.
   * It initialises the variables values and it creates the components.
   */
  initAndCreateComponents(): void {
    this.headerLink = '/header/pm-header.js';

    this.header = document.createElement("pm-header");
    this.headerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    this.headerDiv.classList.add('pm-header-wrapper');
    this.headerDiv.appendChild(this.header);

    document.body.insertBefore(this.headerDiv, document.body.firstChild);
  }    
}

new PM(null);
```

and this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "src",
    "test"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "@types/jasmine",
      "@types/node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es2015.generator",
      "es2015.iterable",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2015.symbol",
      "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  }
}
```

now when I run tsc I get and sdk.js that looks like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var PM = /** @class */ (function () {
        /**
         * @todo remove constructor.
         */
        function PM(mode) {
            if (mode == null || mode == undefined) {
                this.buildGUI();
            }
        }
        /**
         * Build GUI.
         * It builds the GUI by wrapping the body in a container, adding the header and sidebar.
         */
        PM.prototype.buildGUI = function () {
            this.initAndCreateComponents();
            this.insertScript(this.headerLink);
        };
...
```

Now this generated file is supposed to be imported in several html pages, and when I did my research I found that it could only be loaded using require like this:

```
<script data-main="/sdk/sdk.js" src="/sdk/require.js"></script>
```

What I want is a way to load my script without the use of any library, to be loaded like any regular plain javascript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a module system (although I highly recommend you look into using one) you should remove `export` from your class (and from any other symbol in your file) , this will make your module be treated as a simple script file.

You should also add `"module": "none"` to your `tsconfig.json` to let the compiler know you will not be using a module system. This should trigger errors anywhere your code depends on modules (either because you `export` something or you use an `import`)

**Note** Since you will not be using a module system any class/variable/function you declare in your script file will be in the global scope (as they would be for any js file). You may want to consider using namespaces to organize your code and get out of the global scope.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but, I'm gonna have to take a thorough look into module system to decide whether I should change that or not. Many thanks :)